# Is it possible to use a C library with python AppEngine?

Tags: python, c, google-app-engine

I am investigating into if I can use a library like [GHMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghmm/) with my python web service in which runs on AppEngine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no

https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/commontasks

**What third party libraries can I use in my application?**

You can use any pure Python third party libraries in your Google App Engine application. In order to use a third party library, simply include the files in your application's directory, and they will be uploaded with your application when you deploy it to our system. You can import the files as you would any other Python files with your application.

Comment: I am already using third party python libraries, with the service. I had the same impression as your short answer, but I had also to ask :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Google has little control over what compiled C code could do within their infrastructure, and therefore they restrict it.

Answer (score 1):

As @gahooa has said, the generic answer is no.

For more popular libraries that have C dependencies your best option right now is to file a ticket[1], get other to upvote (star) your ticket and have the App Engine add it as a supported library.

[1] http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 yes [you can](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart).

The flexible version of AppEngine allows you to do this, standard does not.

If, like me, you cannot justify the full time running costs of flexible, an alternative is to host the C library on Cloud Run and make API calls to it. Then you have costs of AppEngine standard and Cloud Run, but both are on-demand only.